# Corsair Mouse Buttons Broken - Mouse Buttons Bound To Keys

Tags: 18.04, mouse

I'm running Ubuntu 18 with latest updates and using a Corsair Nightsword mouse. Corsair devices are known to not support Linux well, but up until this issue, everything worked as expected out of the box.

I applied the latest round of updates from Software Updates yesterday. After restarting, the back and forward side buttons on the mouse started typing '1' and '2'.

I tried using xbindkeys, but since the button are sending events for the '1' and '2' keys, anything I bind to the buttons also binds the '1' and '2' key on the keyboard.

I'm not sure where to begin looking for a solution. Any guidance would be appreciated!

xinput

```
    Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair CORSAIR NIGHTSWORD RGB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair CORSAIR NIGHTSWORD RGB Gaming Mouse   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID Keyboard HID Keyboard Consumer Control    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Kingston HyperX 7.1 Audio Consumer Control    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Kingston HyperX 7.1 Audio                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair CORSAIR NIGHTSWORD RGB Gaming Mouse Keyboard  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair CORSAIR NIGHTSWORD RGB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID Keyboard HID Keyboard Consumer Control    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID Keyboard HID Keyboard                 id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID Keyboard HID Keyboard                 id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xev (Forward button)

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0x1e8, subw 0x3200002, time 25248727, (49,33), root:(89,141),
state 0x0, keycode 10 (keysym 0x31, 1), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: FYI: It may help if you're accurate with details. Ubuntu desktop and server releases use *yy.mm* format (with multiple releases per year), where as *yy* is used by *snap* based specialist releases that have only a single release per year, have no GUI (thus no keyboard/mouse) as intended use is for appliances or devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a random post about Logitech mice, I discovered it was the mouse's internal profiles that were causing the trouble.
Somewhere in the process, a profile with the side-buttons (Back and Forward) disabled or remapped was enabled.
The issue was resolved by switching profiles using the top buttons on the mouse until I found one that worked.

Comment: There is an application called piper that allows reprogramming the memory profiles of such devices to a certain degree. You might give it a try.